# c# Action dynamic parameters for multiple functions

Tags: c#, collections, action

I have multiple functions in my project that do exactly the same thing, the only difference among these functions is that the parameters are different in the function signature and in the action method signature which is called in the function for ex.

```
   function DoSomething(string x, datatable dt, Action<string, datatable> methodname ){ methodname(x, dt);}
   function DoSomething(datatable dt1, datatable dt2, Action<datatable, datatable> methodname ){ methodname(dt1, dt2);}
   function DoSomething(Class FOO, datatable dt2, Action<class, datatable> methodname ){ methodname(FOO, dt2);}
```

I am trying to consolidate this code so I can have one function take in any parameters and call the action method. I already put together a function that takes in a  List as the parameter as so:

```
   List<object> list_obj = new List<object>();
   List_obj.Add(Datatable) 
   List_obj.Add(Class FOO)
   function DynamicDoSomething<T>(Action<T> methodname, T Parameter) {methodname(Parameter)}
```

My issue is one this sort of works to get the object to the function, but then I am left with looping thru the List to try create or assign DataTables or classes depending on whats needed in the function. For Ex:

```
     function methodbeingcalled(List<object> objlist){
         foreach(var item in objlist){
           string ObjType = item.GetType().ToString();
                if (ObjType.Equals("System.Data.DataTable"))
                {
                    dt= ((DataTable)item);
                }
                else { foo = ((Foo)item);}
         }
     }
```

Is their a better way to do this bec the foreach to assign seems like a HACK

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your signature looks like this:

```
DoSomething<TInput>(TInput x, DataTable dt, Action<TInput, DataTable> methodname)
```

and then you could call that like this:

```
DoSomething("Some string value.", someDataTable, (input, dt) => { });
```

or like this:

```
DoSomething(someObject, someDataTable, (input, dt) => { });
```

and now in all cases the `TInput` is properly typed.

Comment: thats what I already have, the issue is that there are multiple functions like that that I am trying to consolidate since they all pretty much doing the same thing, that is why I am trying to pass a List object as the parameter with datatables or classes to be used in the action method function

Comment: @AC25, then make the second parameter `List<TObjectList>` and make `List<TObjectList>` the type for the delegate that's passed in. And honestly, based on the question, it didn't look like that's what you already had.

Comment: sorry I didnt realize that I am able to call the function Dosomething<List<object>(methodname, List<obj>) the part that I am trying to find out is that when I get the methodname function with the List<obj> in hand which I get to is their a better way to cast variables then doing a for each like i have above in the methodbeingcalled